# bitwise operation to set decimal variable

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I wrote a light program using bitwise operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int pos;
    unsigned int aaregister = 0;
    unsigned int result = 1;
    aaregister = aaregister|(1 << 0);
    printf("|0: %02X \n", aaregister);
    aaregister = aaregister | 1 << 1;
    printf("|1: %02X \n", aaregister);
    aaregister = aaregister | 0 << 2;
    printf("|2: %02X \n", aaregister);
    aaregister = aaregister | 1 << 3;
    printf("|3: %02X \n", aaregister);
    for (pos = 3; pos>=0;pos--) 
    {
         result = result & (aaregister & (1 >> pos));
        printf(" %d \n", result);
         printf("res : %02X \n", result);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

my purpose is set `aaregister` to binary value 1011 and then set the `result` according to bit position.

if bit pos = 3 `1` so result = 1

if pos = 2 `0` so result = 0

if pos = 1 `1` so result = 1

if pos = 0 `1` so result = 1

but the program doesn't return that !!

what wrong with the c program  ?

Comment: Why not simply "result = (aaregister & (1 << pos)) != 0" ?. No loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer, based on what I believe the expected output is intended to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int pos;
    unsigned int aaregister = 0;
    unsigned int result = 0;
    aaregister |= 1 << 0;
    printf("|0: %02X \n", aaregister);
    aaregister |= 1 << 1;
    printf("|1: %02X \n", aaregister);
    aaregister |= 0 << 2;
    printf("|2: %02X \n", aaregister);
    aaregister |= 1 << 3;
    printf("|3: %02X \n", aaregister);
    for (pos = 3; pos>=0;pos--)
    {
        result = (aaregister >> pos) & 1;
        printf("Pos %d: res : %d\n", pos, result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
|0: 01
|1: 03
|2: 03
|3: 0B
Pos 3: res : 1
Pos 2: res : 0
Pos 1: res : 1
Pos 0: res : 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are shifting the wrong part: instead of shifting `1` to the right (which will produce zero when `pos` is not zero) you should shift `aaregister` to the right, like this:

```
result = result & ((aaregister >> pos) & 1);
```

In addition, the declaration of `result` needs to move inside the loop, so that you reset it back to `1` on each iteration ([demo](http://ideone.com/nhRj39)).

Now that your program is working, here are some important points about bit operations:

**You cannot force a zero into a number by OR-ing** - hence, `aaregister | 0 << 1` operation is pointless. In order to force a zero you need to AND with an inverse, like this:

```
aaregister = aaregister & ~(1 << 1);
```

or better

```
aaregister &= ~(1 << 1);
```

**Compound assignments make your code easier to read** - instead of writing

```
aaregister = aaregister | 1 << 3;
```

write

```
aaregister |= (1 << 3);
```

**Testing a bit can be done in any position** - if you would like to check that position `pos` is set or not, use

```
if (aaregister & (1 << pos)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to set a bit you can use this logic

```
a=(1<<(pos-1))|a;
```